# Combining subjoint distributions to create a larger joint distribution

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, joint-distribution, information-theory, mathematical-statistics

I am trying to construct large joint distributions through smaller joint distributions and I'm not sure how to approach the literature.

I am curious if there exists a function which can take n subjoint distributions and approximate a larger joint distribution.

```
f(P(X,Y), P(X,Z)) = P(X,Y,Z) + e
```

I am also curious whether overlapping variables (variables in both sub joint distributions) lower the error in comparison to disjoint sub joint distributions.

```
P(X,Y,Z,A) - f(P(X,Y,A), P(X,Z)) < P(X,Y,Z,A) - f(P(X,Y), P(Z,A))?
```

I have a feeling that this has something to do with inclusion-exclusion and mutual information.

Comment: bivariate margins - even three of them - do not determine trivariate distributions; typically there would be an infinity of possible solutions. You would have to specify the manner in which you want to combine them.

Comment: For my use-case, its fine if they dont determine as long as I can bound the error. Could you elaborate more and/or point to some literature on this?

Similarly, I'm fine exploring (n-k)variate margins (where n is the full join distribution and k < n) if that simplifies the problem space.

Comment: I can't tell from your question what topics you've already researched. Are you familiar with [copulas, Sklar's Theorem, and the Fréchet–Hoeffding bounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)) and are seeking to generalize those? Are you familiar with [graphical models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_model) and [RBMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_Boltzmann_machine) and seeking a more general model? You're likely to get more answers if you can supply more context.